# How can I find elements by text content with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, text, find

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to find an element based on its content rather than by an **ID** or **class**?

I am attempting to find elements that don't have distinct classes or IDs. (Then I then need to find that element's parent.)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I select a span containing a specific text value, using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424417/how-do-i-select-a-span-containing-a-specific-text-value-using-jquery)

Answer (score 576, accepted):

You can use the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to get elements based on their content.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/9z5du/)

```js
$('div:contains("test")').css('background-color', 'red');
```

```html
<div>This is a test</div>
<div>Another Div</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great, but it is case sensitive. Is there anyway we can do a case insensitive search?

Comment: @DipuRaj: You'd have to use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead.  `$('div').filter(function(){ return $(this).text().toLowerCase() === 'test';})`

Comment: Yes, please use the appraoch **@RocketHazmat** uses, say you have 5 elements all **prefixed with 'Register Contract'** and each has a number suffix. 

You'll end up **selecting them all**, when in reality you only want the element with text: **'Register Contract 26'**.

Comment: Although :contains is case sensitive, it worked for me because I passed the exact text string to be find.

Comment: In case it helps someone else who likes to use spaces in their parens, the following does **not** work: `$('div:contains( "test" )').css('background-color', 'red');`

Comment: This is not working if you are running it all over the the page because all divs will contain the wanted text. Highly recommand to check there is no more other child.

Comment: Not good. In case of nested `div`s, this will return all `div`s until the root div i.e. from where query started.

Comment: `Uncaught DOMException: Document.querySelector: 'div:contains("test")' is not a valid selector`

Comment: It worked for me without **"** : `$('div:contains(test)').css('background-color', 'red');`

Answer (score 108):

In jQuery documentation it says:

> The matching text can appear directly within the selected element, in
>   any of that element's descendants, or a combination

Therefore it is not enough that you use `:contains()` *selector*, you also need to check if the text you search for is the **direct content** of the element you are targeting for, something like that:

```js
function findElementByText(text) {
    var jSpot = $("b:contains(" + text + ")")
                .filter(function() { return $(this).children().length === 0;})
                .parent();  // because you asked the parent of that element

    return jSpot;
}
```

Comment: This solution might fail in following scenario: `<li>Hello <a href='#'>World</a>, How Are You. `. Here if `How` is being searched the condition will fail I think.

Answer (score 30):

Fellas, I know this is old but hey I've this solution which I think works better than all. First and foremost overcomes the Case Sensitivity that the jquery :contains() is shipped with:

```
var text = "text";

var search = $( "ul li label" ).filter( function ()
{
    return $( this ).text().toLowerCase().indexOf( text.toLowerCase() ) >= 0;
}).first(); // Returns the first element that matches the text. You can return the last one with .last()
```

Hope someone in the near future finds it helpful.

Answer (score 25):

Rocket's answer doesn't work.

```
<div>hhhhhh
<div>This is a test</div>
<div>Another Div</div>
</div>
```

I simply modified his [DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/9z5du/870/) and you can see the root DOM is selected.

```
$('div:contains("test"):last').css('background-color', 'red');
```

add "**:last**" selector in the code to fix this.

Comment: This works best when the selector returns multiple results and you need to narrow it down to a specific element where you have no "Id" attribute to reference.

Answer (score 21):

The following jQuery selects div nodes that contain text but have no children, which are the leaf nodes of the DOM tree.

```js
$('div:contains("test"):not(:has(*))').css('background-color', 'red');
```

```html
<div>div1
<div>This is a test, nested in div1</div>
<div>Nested in div1<div>
</div>
<div>div2 test
<div>This is another test, nested in div2</div>
<div>Nested in div2</div>
</div>
<div>
div3
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is the best answer!

Comment: NOTE: this works because of the [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector available in jQuery, which is not part of the [CSS standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes).  [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/winautomation/process-development-tips/web-automation/how-to-use-the-contains-css-selector) seem to have supported such a selector in a previous version of their web engine.

Answer (score 17):

Best way in my opinion.

```
$.fn.findByContentText = function (text) {
    return $(this).contents().filter(function () {
        return $(this).text().trim() == text.trim();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, use the jQuery [`contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector.

Comment: er, no don't: 'contains:' does not do an exact match, only whether the needle is contained (hence name) in the haystack... as others have said here

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

All answers so far do not match *all* *specific* elements containing a *direct* child text node which contains a *specific* text.

Consider the following example. We want to find all hobbits, that is, all `div`s containing a direct child text node, which contains the word "hobbit" (including word borders, ignoring the case).

```js
$(function() {
    
    const ELEMTYPE = Node.ELEMENT_NODE
    const TEXTTYPE = Node.TEXT_NODE
    
    /*
    Behaves a bit like Python's os.walk().
    The `topdown` parameter is not strictly necessary for this example.
    */
    function* walk_text(root, topdown=true) {
        const childs = []
        const textchilds = []
        for (const child of root.childNodes) {
            const childtype = child.nodeType
            if (childtype === ELEMTYPE) {
                childs.push(child)
            } else if (childtype === TEXTTYPE) {
                textchilds.push(child)
            }
        }
        if (topdown) {
            yield [root, textchilds]
        }
        for (const child of childs) {
            yield* walk_text(child, topdown)
        }
        if (!topdown) {
            yield [root, textchilds]
        }
    }
    
    function* walk_matching(startnode, nodepat, textpat) {
        for ( [elem, textchilds] of walk_text(startnode) ) {
            if ( nodepat.test(elem.nodeName) ) {
                for ( const textchild of textchilds ) {
                    if ( textpat.test(textchild.nodeValue) ) {
                        yield elem
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // raw dom node
    let startnode = $('body')[0]
    
    // search for element nodes with names matching this pattern ...
    let nodepat = /^div$/i
    
    // ... containing direct child text nodes matching this pattern
    let textpat = /\bhobbit\b/i
    
    for ( const node of walk_matching( startnode, nodepat, textpat ) ) {
        $(node).css({
            border: '1px solid black',
            color: 'black'
        })
    }

});
```

```css
div {
    margin:10px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    color: silver;
    font-style:italic;
}

div:before {
    display:block;
    content: attr(name);
    font-style:normal;
}

/* Inserted by SO, we are not interested in it */
body + div {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Find the hobbits</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div name='Tolkien'>
            book writer
            <div name='Elrond'>
                elven king
                <div name='Arwen'>elven princess</div>
                <div name='Aragorn'>human king, son-in-law</div>
            </div>
            <div name='Gandalf'>
                wizard, expert for hobbits
                <div name='Bilbo'>
                    old hobbit
                    <div name='Frodo'>
                        young hobbit
                        <div name='Samweis'>best friend hobbit</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div name='Gollum'>ex hobbit</div>
                <div name='Odo'>hobbit</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src= "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The other answers find (when searching for 'hobbit'):

- Rocket Hazmat's answer: *Tolkien, Gandalf, Bilbo, Frodo, Samweis, Gollum, Odo*
- Morgs's answer: *Tolkien*
- yoav barnea's answer: *Gandalf, Frodo*
- Nicholas Sushkin's answer: *Samweis, Gollum, Odo*
- Rocket Hazmat's answer in the comments, Terry Lin's answer, rplaurindo's answer: *Odo*

All of these answers make sense, depending on what you want to do. Choose wise, because Rocket Hazmat's answers, Morgs's answer and Terry Lin's answer partially perform more than two times faster than my solution. I guess that is because they don't need to walk through the whole DOM. Most answers who use `.filter()` perform very fast.