# How do I select a span containing a specific text value, using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I find the span containing the text "FIND ME"

```
<div>
   <span>FIND ME</span>
   <span>dont find me</span>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery find element by text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321896/jquery-find-element-by-text)

Answer (score 142, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

```
$("span:contains('FIND ME')")
```

ETA:

The contains selector is nice, but filtering a list of spans if probably quicker: http://jsperf.com/jquery-contains-vs-filter

```
$("span").filter(function() { return ($(this).text().indexOf('FIND ME') > -1) }); -- anywhere match
$("span").filter(function() { return ($(this).text() === 'FIND ME') }); -- exact match
```

Comment: does that answer my next question?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424509/how-do-i-select-a-span-containing-an-exact-text-value-using-jquery

Comment: Yes. Filter is the answer again, but this time you check the entire .text() value for a match instead of looking for the index. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks Malk! I hadn't heard of filter(). Sometimes it's necessary as contains() is a wildcard comparison so will find 'FIND ME' and 'DON'T FIND ME' which isn't helpful if you need an exact match

Answer (score 10):

Use [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
$("span:contains('FIND ME')")
```

Comment: This does not work. In the OP he has two spans: `find me`, and `dont find me`. You are checking if the span contains this text so you found both.

Answer (score 4):

By the way, if you'd like to use this with a variable, you'd do it this way:

```
function findText() {
    $('span').css('border', 'none');  //reset all of the spans to no border
    var find = $('#txtFind').val();   //where txtFind is a simple text input for your search value
    if (find != null && find.length > 0) {
        //search every span for this content
        $("span:contains(" + find + ")").each(function () {
            $(this).css('border', 'solid 2px red');    //mark the content
        });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this will work

```
var span;
$('span').each(function(){
  if($(this).html() == 'FIND ME'){
    span = $(this);
  }
});
```

Comment: how can I do this in Python using selenium ?