# How do I select a span containing an exact text value, using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select element based on EXACT text contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338439/select-element-based-on-exact-text-contents)

How do I select a span containing an exact text value, using jquery?

```
<div>
   <span>find me</span>
   <span>dont find me</span>
   <span>xfind mex</span>
   <span>_find me_</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$('span')
  .filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == 'find me'; })
  .css('color','red');
```

`.filter` allows you to apply logic to the elements and return only those that match your test(s) back.

---

In case you want a better integrated version, here's a `:text()` selector:

```
(function($){
    $.expr[':'].text = function(obj, index, meta, stack){
        return ($(obj).text() === meta[3])
    };
})(jQuery);

$('span:text("find me")').css('color','red');
```