# how to find array values inside an element and add jquery class to it

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops

I am trying to find array values inside an element and then add a css class to it. Is my technique wrong? Can someone please help me.

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
for (numbers < 1; numbers <= 20; numbers++) {
  $('td').find(numbers).addClass('active');
}
```

```css
td.active {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1
      <td>
        <td>2
          <td>
            <td>3
              <td>
                <td>4
                  <td>
                    <td>5
                      <td>
                        <td>6
                          <td>
                            <td>7
                              <td>
                                <td>8
                                  <td>
                                    <td>9
                                      <td>
                                        <td>10
                                          <td>
                                            <tr/>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td>11
                                                <td>
                                                  <td>12
                                                    <td>
                                                      <td>13
                                                        <td>
                                                          <td>14
                                                            <td>
                                                              <td>15
                                                                <td>
                                                                  <td>16
                                                                    <td>
                                                                      <td>17
                                                                        <td>
                                                                          <td>18
                                                                            <td>
                                                                              <td>19
                                                                                <td>
                                                                                  <td>20
                                                                                    <td>
                                                                                      <tr/>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your table HTML is broken as you can see from the formatting of the snippet - you're missing the `</td>`

Comment: … and `<tr/>` has to be replaced by `</tr>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I select a span containing a specific text value, using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424417/how-do-i-select-a-span-containing-a-specific-text-value-using-jquery)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan HTML allows for omitting the end tag on `<td>` elements, even when naive tidy tools don't know that :). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4020374/215552

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks, was not aware of that. I would argue it's terrible practice to write code in that way, though. The OP's code was incorrect either way, as they had extra unnecessary `<td>` where the `</td>` should have been.

Comment: Although I suspect @pv619 has made an error in the html (`<tr/>` is obviously an error), having closing tags for tr and td are not required in html5.

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan and Takit for spotting it out :) Sorry Heretic if was similar and Luke thanks you for the information, i was aware of it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's several issues here. Firstly your HTML is broken. The `td` elements needs to be closed properly with `</td>`. Then the `<tr />` need to be `</tr>`.

Secondly your `for` loop syntax is incorrect. `numbers` is a reference to the array, so using it as the iterator is going to cause odd behaviour. You instead need to define an integer and increment that. Then you can use that integer to retrieve values from `numbers` by index within the `for` loop.

Finally, `find()` is expecting a selector to search for child elements within the `td`. Instead you need to use `filter()` to match the text of each cell. The filter function needs to take the text of the cell and use `indexOf()` to determine if that value is within the array contents. Also note that when using this method you no longer need the `for` loop at all. Try this:

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
$('td').filter(function() {
  return numbers.indexOf(parseInt($(this).text(), 10)) != -1;
}).addClass('active');
```

```css
td.active {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Closing tags are optional for `<tr>` and `<td>` in html5 -- "A td element’s end tag may be omitted if the td element is immediately followed by a td or th element, or if there is no more content in the parent element." https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html

Comment: @Luke thanks was not aware of that. However, that's a terrible idea to write code without the closing tags, IMO. The OP's code was incorrect either way, as they had extra unnecessary `<td>` where the `</td>` should have been.

Comment: Wow!!!! thank you soo much Rory for the detailed explanation and with a solution. It works great. Only one issue i face with this is that, when numbers have [10, 20, 30] it also highlights [1, 2, 3]. Can you give a suggestion on that please? Apart from that it works like a charm thank you once again :)

Comment: @pv619 I can't replicate that behaviour - the snippet above will only highlight exact value matches, so `10` will not match `100` or `1000`, for example

Comment: It was me, because I am trying to get the values from the URL parameter and tried to match it with the <td> element. Thank you once again for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

As Rory said, make sure you close all  elements correctly.

Try out this code. It filters out all  elements with the specified numbers as inner html and sets the css class.

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  $('td').filter(function() { 
    return $(this).html() == numbers[i];
  }).addClass('active');
}
```

As you can see, you must iterate the array to get the specified values.

Comment: It works :) thank you Mike for your help really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you like tiny, reusable functions like I do, here's how I would do it:

```
const activeNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];

function getNumberText($elt) {
    return parseInt($elt.text(), 10);
}

function isActiveNumber(n) {
    return activeNumbers.includes(n);
}

function updateActiveClass(elt) {
    const $elt = $(elt);
    const n = getNumberText($elt);
    $elt.toggleClass('active', isActiveNumber(n));
}

function highlightActiveCells(selector) {
    $(selector).find('td').each(function () { updateActiveClass(this); });
}

highlightActiveCells('table'); // or a better selector, like a class or id
```

Comment: Thanks Luke, for your help and really appreciate it :)