# How can do select tag as value pair?

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

I have a pair of values. 
I don't want a `<key, value>` pair.
I want a `<value,value>` pair.

I have created a select tag. and its options are the pairs.

```
<option value="value1" >value2</option>
```

The code below selects the  options that have `value=i`.

```
options = $("#myselect option[value='"+i+"']");
```

I want to select the option that `value=val1` and `text = val2`.

Any other idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery find element by text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321896/jquery-find-element-by-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery's `filter()` for this

```
        var i = 1;
        var options = $("#myselect option[value='value" + i + "']").filter(function(){
           return $(this).text() == 'value'+(i+1)
        });
        console.log(options);
```

#### HTML

```
  <select id="myselect">
     <option value="value1">value1</option>
     <option value="value1">value2</option>
     <option value="value1">value3</option>
  </select>
```

selects `<option value="value1">value2</option>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to further filter the selection:

```
options = $("#myselect option[value="+i+"]:contains('value"+j+"')");
```

Comment: that _make up your mind_ comment was epic. May be because of invalid formatting not displaying the `<value,value>`? lol :D