# Find td with specific text, and operate on the td right after that one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, html-table

I'm not very familiar with jQuery selectors, so would like some help.

I have a table like this:

```
<table class="test">
  <tr>
    <td>Section Heading 1</td><td>Section Text 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Section Heading 2</td><td>Section Text 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Section Heading 3</td><td>Section Text 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Section Heading 4</td><td>Section Text 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Section Heading 5</td><td>Section Text 5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I need to do is find the `td` containing a specific text, and the operate on the text in the `td` on its right.

For example, say I want to find the `td` containing the text `Section Heading 4`, and the concatenate the text contained in the `td` to it's right, with the text `hello`, so that `Section Text 4` becomes `Section Text 4 hello` ..

Which jQuery selector(s) can be used for this purpose ?

Comment: Chekc [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321896/jquery-find-element-by-text)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My initial answer missed the point about updating the text,  here is a sample with this included:

```
$(".test td:contains(Heading 1)")
    .next().text(function(){
        return $(this).text() + " Hello"
    });
```

I don't believe you can use the append method as I think it only works to add html tags.

Comment: I have edited my answer after testing it with this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h4Txd/

Answer (score 10):

First, you want to use [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
jQuery( "td:contains(text)" );
```

Then, you can use [.next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
jQuery( "td:contains(text)" ).next().append("Hello");
```

Here's a working snippet to demonstrate usage:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("td:contains(Text to Find)").next().append(" Hello");
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Text</td>
      <td>More Text</td>
      <td>YMT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text to Find</td>
      <td>Modify:</td>
      <td>Do nothing here</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Ahmad - It works.  You just have to put the desired text in it, such as: `jQuery("td:contains(Heading 1)")....`

Answer (score 4):

jQuery has [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) pseudo class :

```
$('td:contains("Section Heading 4")').next().text(function(_,t){
    return t + ' Hello';
})
```

Be carefull, `:contains` is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

```
$(function() {
    var searchText = "Section Heading 3";
    var output = "";
    $("td").each(function(i, item) {
        if($(item).html() == searchText) {
            output = $(item).html();
            output += $(item).closest("td").html()
        }
    });

    console.log(output);
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5ELLM/

Comment: Nice function.  I'd upvote, but the OP specifically asked about a jQuery selector, which you are not using...

Answer (score 0):

```
var tds=$("table.test").find("td");
var td,i;
for(i=0;i<tds.size();i++) {
  td=tds.eq(i);
  if (td.text().indexOf("Section Heading 4")!=-1) {
    td.next().text(td.next().text()+"hello");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for information

`var data ="Search string"
$('#table1 td:contains('+data+')').next().text();`