# Find td with specific text, and operate on the ALL td's on its right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This may seem a little similar to my last question ([Find td with specific text, and operate on the td right after that one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339462/find-td-with-specific-text-and-operate-on-the-td-right-after-that-one#21339535)), but this is a different actually ..

I have a table like this, this time:

```
<table class="test">
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td><td>Text 1-1</td><td>Text 1-2</td> ...... <td>Text 1-n</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td><td>Text 2-1</td><td>Text 2-2</td> ...... <td>Text 2-n</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3</td><td>Text 3-1</td><td>Text 3-2</td> ...... <td>Text 3-n</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 4</td><td>Text 4-1</td><td>Text 4-2</td> ...... <td>Text 4-n</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 5</td><td>Text 5-1</td><td>Text 5-2</td> ...... <td>Text 5-n</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Basically it has rows, and now it has an unlimited number of columns.

I need to right a `td` with a specific text, and then operate on ALL `td`s on its right. The text to find will always be from `td`s on the left most side, as it will be a row heading text.

So for example, I may want to find a `td` with text `Row 3`, and then I will need to append `xyz` to the texts of all `td`s on the right of this `td` (which contains text `Row 3`) ..

So in my example, all `td`s on the right of `td` containing `Row 3` will have their texts changed:

```
Text 3-1 --> Text 3-1xyz
Text 3-2 --> Text 3-2xyz
.
.
.
Text 3-n --> Text 3-nxyz
```

How do I solve this one ?

Comment: reading the manual to see what jquery's capable of would be a good start: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/  DOM's a tree, and standard tree manipulation methods, including finding nearby related elements, are what you need.

Comment: Use the same but instead of `next` use `nextAll` or `siblings` http://jsfiddle.net/h4Txd/1/

Comment: Thanks .. nextAll() did the trick ! :D .. If you make an answer, I'll mark it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other kind of resources that will let you select elements on the DOM like [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) or [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/), based on the code you already have just change that:

```
$(".test td:contains(Row 3)")
.nextAll().text(function(){
    return $(this).text() + "xyz"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With jquery you can use [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) but it's not suitable, use [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

```
$("table.test td").each(function() {
  if ($(this).html() == "Text 2-1")
    $(this).append("xyz");
});
```

http://jsbin.com/IrEpeTE/1/edit

For row use "eq()", get 5th rows like this :

```
$("table.test tr:eq(4) td").each(function() {
   if ($(this).html()!="Row 5")
       $(this).append("xyz");
});
```

or :

```
$("table.test tr td").each(function() {
  if ($(this).parent().children().html()=="Row 5" && $(this).html()!="Row 5")
       $(this).append("xyz");
});
```