# Edit text without class or ID

Tags: javascript, html, css, client-side-scripting

I need to format certain line of text on the client side, but I cannot modify the actual code. The HTML is generated dynamically but I can put the code snippet with JS and CSS on top to style it. Here is the HTML:

```
<td role="gridcell" class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">Daily Reports</td>
<td role="gridcell" class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">Construction</td>
<td role="gridcell" class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">Administration</td>
```

Since all Td's have the same role and class, but I need to only change word Administration to "Category - Administration", how can I do this? I tried the following script but it didn't work.

```
<script>
document.getElementByName("Administration").innerHTML = "Category - Administration";
</script>
```

Greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Are there always just three td's like this?

Comment: loop td with class gridcell - then make if statment on innerHTML and change just a line that you need

Comment: if the cell is always at the same place in the HTML table , you can select it via nth-child, . If you shared enough of your html table and if that cell is always at the same position, then i could make an answer describing the idea with a working demo based on CSS without js needs. looks like header ....

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by comparing the text content of the cells. Of course this is error prone and if the text is somehow slightly different it will break. But if there is no other way around it, the sample below should help you.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.ms-cellstyle').forEach(cell => {
  if (cell.textContent === 'Administration') {
    cell.textContent = 'Category - Administration';
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td role="gridcell" class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">Daily Reports</td>
    <td role="gridcell" class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">Construction</td>
    <td role="gridcell" class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">Administration</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's always the third `td` you can use plain css `td:eq(3){/*style here*/}` otherwise you can use javascript, there's also a useful jQuery function - https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: You can also find this post helpful as an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339462/find-td-with-specific-text-and-operate-on-the-td-right-after-that-one

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.qurySelectorAll` and check the textContent and replace that text where it matches

```js
document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(function(item) {
  if (item.textContent.trim() === 'Administration') {

    item.textContent = 'Some other text'
  }

})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td role="gridcell" class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">Daily Reports</td>
    <td role="gridcell" class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">Construction</td>
    <td role="gridcell" class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">Administration</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To avoid `forEach` you can use conventional `for` loop

```js
let m = document.querySelectorAll('td');
for (var item = 0; item < m.length; item++) {
  if (m[item].textContent.trim() === 'Administration') {
    m[item].textContent = 'Some other text'
  }

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td role="gridcell" class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">Daily Reports</td>
    <td role="gridcell" class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">Construction</td>
    <td role="gridcell" class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">Administration</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

if 1document.qurySelectorAll`is not supported then use`document.getElementsByTagName`

Comment: Note IE doesn't support forEach on NodeList

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to edit text without a `class` or `id`:

```
$('.ms-cellstyle').each(function() {
   if ($(this).text()=="Administration")
   $(this).text("Category - Administration");
});
```

Comment: and it is more or less same approach for pure js

Answer (score 0):

First make sure this `<td>` are inside `<tr>` and `<table>`. Use `.querySelectorAll` to get all elements in the document with `class="ms-cellstyle"` then use .forEach() method to call a provided function once for each element in an array

```
document.querySelectorAll('.ms-cellstyle').forEach(td => {(td.textContent == 'Administration') ? td.textContent = 'Category - Administration': ;});
```

Reference: [.querySelectorAll](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp) [.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp)