# Selecting element with specific class and value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to select element with class MyClass and value MyValue, but without using each?
I tried something like:

```
$(".MyClass").find("[value='MyValue']")
$(".MyClass[value='MyValue']")
```

This is example: http://jsfiddle.net/HQaG5/
It works if i use hard coded value for select element.

Comment: And how did that fail? What went wrong? What HTML are you working with?

Comment: It's hard to see your problem, the second one does what you seem to want. Can you build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: unless the element is an input or you specifically set the attribute "value", value will not exist

Comment: Is the value dynamic or not ?

Comment: does op said, he want to get the object according to 'html' or 'text' instead of 'value'?

Comment: Um, your example doesn't work. But this one does: http://jsfiddle.net/HQaG5/2/

Answer (score 1):

You want [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) :

```
$( ".MyClass:contains('MyValue')" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: [jquery find element by text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321896/jquery-find-element-by-text)

You can use the `:contains` selector to find elements containing text.

But if you want to match an exact string then .filter is the better option

Answer (score 0):

If the element is an input and you want to search after property value you can use `.filter()`

```
$('.MyClass').filter(function(){
       return this.value=="MyValue";
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zMT32/)

Comment: the op doesn't want to use loops

Comment: @zzlalani - are you with the OP? I don't see anywhere in the question that mentions that.

Comment: `but without using each`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get the select box element that has the specified value selected (which seems to be the case based on your fiddle), then you can use this…

```
$(".MyClass option:selected[value='MyValue']").parent()
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HQaG5/1/)

However, I would question *why* you want to do this, as it seems kind of backwards.