# jQuery hide element with between element text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to hide element with text from `div` element. for example i have this element :

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; 
            bottom: 10px; z-index: 100000; 
            visibility: visible; display: block; 
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
            text-shadow: none; font-family: sans-serif; 
            font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; 
            padding: 2px; border: 1px solid rgb(68, 0, 0); 
            background-color: rgb(221, 0, 0);">
   hi all users
 </div>
```

in this code i want to hide this div with using `hi all users` text. please help me. thanks

Comment: The div is already hidden...what do you mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery find element by text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321896/jquery-find-element-by-text)

Comment: Have you tried anything before posting?

Comment: Have you considered giving it a class? Then you can just write `$('.myClass').hide();` instead of trying to target the element by it's `.html()` content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `:contains` selector for this:

```
$('div:contains("hi all users")').css('display', 'none');
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wv6rU/)