# Jquery. Find all <tr> containing text from selected <option>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to show all lines contaning selected text from option after click on button, this is my code:

```
<select>
 <option>text1</option>
 <option>text2</option>
 <option>text3</option>
 <option>text4</option>
</select>
<button class="show"></button>
<button class="hide"></button>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>text1</td><td>....</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>text2</td><td>....</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>text3</td><td>....</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>text1</td><td>....</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I try to do something like this but it doesnt work:

```
$(function(){
  b = $("tr");
  $(".show").on("click", function(){
   var a = $("select option:selected").text();
   $(b).hide();
   if ($("tr:contains('"+a+"')").length) 
    $(this).closest(tr).show();
 });

 $(".hide").on("click", function(){
  $(b).show();              
 });    
});
```

Can someone help me, pls :)

Comment: Not related with question: since `b` is already jQuery object, there is no need to wrap it with `$()`. You can simply use `b.hide()` and `b.show();`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery find element by text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321896/jquery-find-element-by-text)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/32bitkid/a4b4oyvq/2/

Comment: What will happen if use contains with `td` instead of `tr`and reading the parent tr object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : You can use `each` to check each `tr` for selected option text and make it visible. No need to use `closest('tr')` as `$(this)` itself is a `TR`.

```
$(function(){
  b = $("tr");
  $(".show").on("click", function(){
   var a = $("select option:selected").text();
   b.hide();
   //if ($("tr:contains('"+a+"')").length) 
   // $(this).closest(tr).show();
   b.each(function(){
     if($(this).text().indexOf(a)!=-1)
     {
       $(this).show();
     }
  });
 });

 $(".hide").on("click", function(){
  b.show();              
 });    
});
```

Comment: Instead you should use toggle: `$(this).toggle($(this).text().indexOf(a)!=-1);` and don't hide all `b` by default

Comment: @A.Wolff mm I know about .toggle() but I think it would be necessary to me if I had one button to show and hide, no?

Comment: @A.Wolff not _should_, but _can_. Actually `b.hide();` and `b.filter(":contains('" + a + "')").show();` is shorter and easier.

Comment: I'd recommend relying on the `onclick` property of buttons rather than using classes to trigger this action. Also, I'd recommend isolating the functions to the table in question to minimize impact.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar not enough reputation for +1 :(

Comment: @Regent `should` was regarding code in this specific answer :) And ya, i prefer your way, more readable ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need something like this. Don't pollute global space and use proper selectors. And there is no need to wrap a jQuery object again.

```
$(function() {
    var b = $("table");
    $(".show").on("click", function() {
        var a = $("select option:selected").text();
        b.find("tr").hide().end().find("td:contains('" + a + "')").parent().show();
    });
    $(".hide").on("click", function() {
        b.find("tr").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: @MohitArora while chaining is indeed possible, it doesn't really "good" code, since code line is very long and difficult to read-understand on **quick** view.

Comment: @AmitJoki `var b = $("table");` should be inside `$(function() {});` - otherwise it will not work at all, if `<script>` is in `<head>`

Comment: @Regent yup, I copied OP's code which had bad indentation so, that blocks were different, which is why I had put that outside. Only now, I realised and edited. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `contains` cause match any element that simple contains test(Select all elements that contain the specified text). Bu you can use `each` and match any td with same text and show parent(`tr`) like:

```js
b = $("tr");
$(".show").on("click", function() {
  var a = $("select option:selected").text();
  $(b).hide();
  $("td").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == a) {
      $(this).parents("tr").show();
    }
  });
});

$(".hide").on("click", function() {
  $(b).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>text1</option>
  <option>text2</option>
  <option>text3</option>
  <option>text4</option>
</select>
<button class="show">show</button>
<button class="hide">hide</button>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>....</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text2</td>
    <td>....</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text3</td>
    <td>....</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>....</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your buttons run functions directly here.

```
function show() {
   var needle = $("select option:selected").text();
   $('#myTable td').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() === needle) $(this).show();
   });
}
function hide() {
   var needle = $("select option:selected").text();
   $('#myTable td').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() === needle) $(this).hide();
   });
}
```

[Take a look at this (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ld1s64y/).