# select an element in javascript/jquery by its html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Imagine I have the following HTML:

```
<div>
     <p> text 1 </p>
     .. some content ..
</div>

<div>
     <p> text 2 </p>
     .. some content ..
</div>
```

I want to select the divs by the content of text, is it possible ? and how can id do it ? thanks !!

Comment: how about to use `$("p").parent()`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321896/jquery-find-element-by-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes possible,
Try something like this

```
$( "div:contains('John')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
$('div:contains("test")').css('background-color', 'blue');
```

Same thing explained here as detail [Selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)