# jQuery Hide Element Containing Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On a page, how can I hide the  containing the  with the text "Product Tags"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('h2:contains("Product Tags")').hide();
```

See [jquery find element by text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321896/jquery-find-element-by-text) and [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: This hides the whole page. I just want to hide the parent <h2> tag over the <span>Product Tags</span>

Comment: @RickHelston, corrected answer

Comment: @RickHelston, did it work? My correction was sublte(just added h2 before ':') Just want to make sure you got it