# How to Add attr ID Based on Value use jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to add attr DIV on one of the list according to the values in UL LI as below.

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I hope I can add to the list `About`, but failed.

I use the code like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(function() {
$('#menu li').html("About").attr("id","active")
}); 
</script>
```

But it did not work. There is a solution?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what exactly you are trying to accomplish.  From my understanding you want to add a DIV tag to the list item based on some criteria is that correct?

Comment: I mean this. I want to add this kind of code in html `<li><a id="active" href="about.html">About</a></li>` **ID active** automatically appear because they have text `About`.
Is this possible?

Comment: Have updated my answer in light of your comment. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321896/jquery-find-element-by-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target an element by its content using the `:contains` selector. In this case, the `id` attribute will be added to the `a` element within your list that contains the text 'About':

```
$('#menu li a:contains("About")').attr("id","active");
```

Result:

```
<li><a href="about.html" id="active">About</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$(function(){
    $("#menu li a:contains('About')").parent().attr("id", "active");
})
```