# javascript replace text after the page has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to remove/hide a piece of text that loads on my page.

The element doesn't have an id to relate to so I want to use a text-specific method.

Let's say the text is:"remove this line of text".
The html looks like this:

```
<div class="aClassName">
<p>
    <strong>remove this line of text</strong>
    ... the rest of the content.
</p>
```

I have tried the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('remove this line of text', '');
});
```

Didn't work. So I tried this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("body").children().each(function () {
       $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/remove this line of text/g,"") );
    });
});
```

Didn't work. The idea is that after the page is loaded it removes the line.
It doesn't produces any errors as well. Not even in the firebug.

Anyone?

Comment: You can remove the DOM element like `$(".aClassName > p > strong:contains('remove this line of text')").remove()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7321960/4478897

Comment: Don't re-set entire sections of html, like `body`'s html, as the html will have to be re-parsed and re-rendered

Comment: it would be so much more effective to make a span with an id, class or whatever... searching for content is much longer... depends on your performances needs...

Answer (score 2):

**Target Elements Based On Their Content**

You could accomplish this using the [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) pseudoselector in jQuery that would allow you to target certain elements based on their contents :

```
$(function(){
   // This will remove any strong elements that contain "remove this line of text"
   $('strong:contains("remove this line of text")').remove();
});
```

You can [see a working example of this here](http://jsbin.com/hapalu/edit?html,output).

**Broader Approach (Just Targets Elements Based On Selectors)**

If you wanted a more simply target it by a more general selector (i.e. any `<strong>` tags that appear beneath a class called `aClassName` :

```
$('.aClassName strong').remove();
```

You can [see an example of this approach here](http://jsbin.com/gozoso/3/edit?html,output).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) and [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/), i.e.:

```js
$('.aClassName').find('strong').text("123");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aClassName">
<p>
    <strong>remove this line of text</strong>
    ... the rest of the content.
</p>
```

---

Or simply:

```
$('strong:contains("remove this line of text")').text("New text");
```

---

**Update:**

After analyzing the link supplied on the comments, you can use the following:

```
$('.payment_method_mollie_wc_gateway_ideal').find('strong').text("");
```

Comment: I have tried the following in my header, right before the `</head>` But didn't work. Even the footer didn't work:`
    <script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $('.payment_box').find('strong').text("remove this line of text.");
  });
    </script>`

Comment: For some strange reason it won't fly. Please check: https://www.cupsandleafs.com/shop/?lang=en and just add something to the cart. When you go to the checkout page; int he payment options it says "Test modus ingeschakeld." I want that line removed!

Comment: No I wish. Then I could just remove this line :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111443/discussion-between-pedro-lobito-and-interactive).