# Changing the colour of Daily Mail links doesn't work on Google results pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension which consists essentially of this (using jQuery):

```
$('a[href*="dailymail"]').css({'background':'#333'})
```

and it works just fine on regular links.

It doesn't work on Google search results, however, because the `href` part of the link is actually a google redirect URL, and the actual URL is in a `data-href` attribute.

My problem is that

```
$('a[data-href*="dailymail"]').css({'background':'#333'})
```

doesn't work. Do I have a problem with matching the attribute/value, or with Google's search results page, or what?

TIA for any thoughts.

Comment: It would help if you could show us an example of the `<a>` elements you're trying to select

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Open a Google search for "dailymail", inspect the page - I think that was straightforward enough from OP.

Comment: that selection should work: https://jsfiddle.net/jolmos/05gr9pfx/

Comment: @Xan Google's SERPs can change between users. Hence my request to see a concrete example of what the OP wants to find. Not to mention every question should be self-contained.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I agree with the last argument, yes.

Comment: @AmbroseChapel Maybe it's worth selecting by text in the link like in this SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321896/jquery-find-element-by-text) Then you can select elements using:  `$('a:contains("daily mail")') `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely your problem is when the code executes.

Google page loads its search results dynamically (for example, for Instant purposes). If your code executes in a content script, that only guarantees that it executes after static DOM was parsed.

`$(selector).css()` operates by adding inline styles to elements that are matched by the time the code runs. So, results (that are added later) are unaffected.

---

The most obvious solution is to simply inject CSS, not JS code:

```
"content_scripts" : [{
  "matches": ["*://*/*"],
  "css": ["dailymail.css"]
}]
```

```css
a[href*="dailymail"], a[data-href*="dailymail"] {
  background: #333;
}
```

This should be specific enough to apply; if not, try adding `!important`.

If you want to control this programmatically, consider adding a `<style>` element to the page.

Alternatively still, you can [watch the page for newly added links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener).

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't know you could inject CSS! I will test ASAP, but not in a position to do that right now.