# Js How to define element by value of itself

Tags: jquery, dom

I know maybe couldn't do that 
Ex:

```
 <div class="dv1">
      <span correct="sp1"> D </span>
      <span correct="sp2"> C </span>
      <span correct="sp3"> Z </span>
 </div>
```

I can define like this :

```
$(".dv1 span[correct=sp2]").addClass("active");
```

Other way I want like this :

```
$(".dv1 span[text=C]").addClass("active");
```

So maybe there are other ways do the same right ? Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery find element by text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321896/jquery-find-element-by-text)

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

`$('.dv1 span').filter(function(index) { return ($(this).text()).trim() === "D"? $(this) : false; });`

```js
var element = $('.dv1 span').filter(function(index) { return ($(this).text()).trim() === "D"? $(this) : false; });
element.addClass('active')
```

```css
.active{
   color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dv1">
      <span correct="sp1"> D </span>
      <span correct="sp2"> C </span>
      <span correct="sp3"> Z </span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
  $(".dv1 span").each(function(){
    if($(this).text().trim() == 'C'){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the second way works. Here there is another way:

```
$(".dv1").find('span[correct=sp2]').addClass("active");
```

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/f28p8gzv/) is working.