# Trying to find an element based on the text content

Tags: javascript, xpath

I'm trying to find an element based on the text inside. For example, to find this link:

```
<a href="#">Foobar</a>
```

Using the codes below I get `null` on `console.log(matchingElement)` in both cases

```js
var xpath = "a[text()='Foobar']";
var matchingElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
console.log(matchingElement);


xpath = "a[contains(text(),'Foobar')]";
matchingElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
console.log(matchingElement);
```

```html
<a href="#">Foobar</a>
```

Comment: If you are comfortable using jQuery, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321896/jquery-find-element-by-text)

Comment: @mplungjan nope. thats `querySelector()` and not xpath

Comment: @zeropublix - please read the answer. It is showing XPath solution

Comment: @mplungjan ok. maybe.. Id let it pass though.

Comment: @mplungjan I'd support that dupe-vote.

Comment: `var xpath = "//a[contains(., 'Foobar')]";`