# How can i hide a div when another div contains specific text?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page with the following code:

```
<div class="box1">Free</div>
<div class="box2">$100</div>
```

I want to check the page and every time the "box1" div contains the text "Free" to remove entirely the "box2" div.

I tried something like that with jQuery

```
$('.box1("Free")') {
$('.box2').hide();
}
```

but doesn't work. What i 'm doing wrong?

[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/g0z1yuzL/3/)

Comment: just check if the div `.text() == 'Free'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery find element by text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321896/jquery-find-element-by-text)

Comment: @JoshKisb Actually it's better to check for `.text() === 'Free'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method to retrieve text from `box1`

```
if ( $('.box1').text() === 'Free' ) {
  $('.box2').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This snippet will be helpful:

```
if($('.box1').text() === "Free") {
  $('.box2').hide();
}
```

Comment: Yep! it worked its the same answer already posted @Arkej Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$(document).ready(function (){
            $('.box1:contains(Free)') {
                 $('.box2').hide();
      }
   });
```

For more info.
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_sel_contains