# How to check that an anchor with specific text exist?

Tags: css-selectors

I want to check the existence of this element on my html page

```
<a  ...>Intranet XXX Portal</a>
```

Via the console, I see that my element is there :

```
> $('a').text == "Intranet XXX Portal"
< true
```

But what I need is a selector where I can test the existence of the element via 
".length > 0"

When I do the following, I always get an empty result.

```
> $('a[text="Intranet XXX Portal"]')
> $('a[innertext="Intranet XXX Portal"]')
> $('a[content="Intranet XXX Portal"]')
< []
```

What selector will return me a $('a???).length > 0 ?

REM: For this particular page, $ refers to the browser jQuery.

Comment: Why don't you assign a class to that <a> element ? So you can grab it easily with $ after that

Comment: I am not the creator of the html page...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: find element by text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321896/jquery-find-element-by-text)

Comment: @JosephMarie see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the existence of that element by doing

```
if ($('a').html('Intranet XXX Portal').length > 0) {
    console.log(true)
}
else {
    console.log(false)
}
```

Hope it helps.