# How to get exact div tag matching selector using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to get the exact tag (not parents) that matching jquery selector.
this is my code:

```
var tagList = $('div:contains("Hello")');
alert(tagList.length);
```

this selector returns a list of tag (length is 4) that are all parent div of matching tag.

```
<div>
  <div>
     <div>
        <div> Hello </div>   //I want to get only this element
     </div>
  </div>
     <div>     //I also tried to get deepest children but result contains this siblings of parents too.
     </div>
</div>
```

How to reduce result to only one element that matching the rule.

Comment: Take the [last](https://api.jquery.com/last/#last) element from the returned jQuery object ..?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: find element by text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22778570/2185135)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am using `filter` method to check `children`, If it has **no** `child`, Then **that's the element** that you want.

[Learn more about **contains**,**filter** and **wrap** methods of jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)

```js
var tagList = $('div:contains("Hello")').filter(function(){
    return this.children.length === 0;
  });
console.log(tagList.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
     <div>
        <div> Hello </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set an id to identify the div

```js
var tagList = $('#hello').text();
alert(tagList.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div id="hello">Hello</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>     //I also tried to get deepest children but result contains this siblings of parents too.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cannot set id for dynamic data. The same time, The text content can be exist in may elements along with other texts. But you can't set same id for each.

Comment: I don't want to set id.

Comment: These days, it's best to avoid setting IDs unless you have a specific reason to use one.  They clutter up the global scope.  Browsers are plenty fast at using selectors, and the APIs have been improved for many years now.