# jquery append to element that contains specific text

Tags: jquery

I have the following html which is a Bootstrap card with two nested cards.

```
<div id="myCard" class="card-body">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            card a
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            card b
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I insert html into the `card-body` that contains the text "card b" in the `card-header` using JQuery?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find elements by text content with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321896/how-can-i-find-elements-by-text-content-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loose traversing (more stable if the elements get wrapped):

```js
$('.card-header:contains(card b)')
  .parents('.card')
  .find('.card-body')
  .text('INSERTED TEXT');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myCard" class="card-body">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            card a
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            card b
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

More strict traversing:

```js
$('.card-header:contains(card b)')
  .parent()
  .children('.card-body')
  .text('INSERTED TEXT');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myCard" class="card-body">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            card a
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            card b
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```